# Backbone.js multiple combined routes from various apps

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a central web app called a 'customer file' which contains all information related to a particular customer. We're just re-developing this using backbone for our modular components e.g. Orders and Contacts (both as Backbone.Model)

Is it possible to have a URL such as `site.com/file#general/contact/:contact_id/order/:order_id` in Backbone.js? Where `/order` refers to the Order model, and `contact` refers to the Contact model and view is just an anchor tag for a position on the page (`<a name="general"></a>`) (which is used by CSS selectors to determine what tab to display)?

The reason we need this kind of URL is that so if a staff member has a customer's file open to a particular call log, with a particular order on a particular view, if they share the URL, the other person sees the same thing (without having to click through everything again)

Does there need to be one main router which includes all combinations of routes? E.G.:

```
"general/contact/:id/call/:call_id":"contactCard",
"sales/contact/:id/call/:call_id":"contactCard",
"billing/contact/:id/call/:call_id":"contactCard",
"distribution/contact/:id/call/:call_id":"contactCard",
"legal/contact/:id/call/:call_id":"contactCard",

"general/contact/:id":"contactCard",
"sales/contact/:id":"contactCard",
"billing/contact/:id":"contactCard",
"distribution/contact/:id":"contactCard",
"legal/contact/:id":"contactCard",
```

...

Or is there another way around this? I would prefer if my routers could be separated based on the models, but not sure if that will be possible considering how it seems the router works? I've looked at using [subroutes](http://www.geekdave.com/?p=13), but I don't think thats what I need.

Comment: are you able to control what your server renders when you hit, for example, `general/contact`?

Comment: Yeah, I can control that. At the moment I am using `site.com/contact_id/12345/order_id/764238746#general` and storing JS variables in the page as the `:id` to be used (to open that contact/order), so if I hard-coded these links into what they click on to open the page, I'd have no issue. But when staff interact with the page, and they display contacts/calls/orders (without reloading the page to get the new URL), how can they share that URL? At the moment the URL seems to only be able to have one hash path